# Horizontal Scrollbar (Bug?) in Google Chrome

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ubuntu-10.04, scrollbar

Anyone else seeing this? Ever since 2 or 3 days ago, I've been seeing this quirk where 1 in 10 websites have this Google Chromium on Ubuntu Linux 10.04 LTS issues of a horizontal scrollbar, while Chrome for Windows doesn't have this issue. This was not happening to me perhaps 3 days ago, but I received a Chromium update and it's been doing this ever since.

I'm on Google Chromium 10.0.648.204 on Ubuntu Linux 10.04 LTS.

Comment: Give me a link - I'm running Chrome in Linux now (and if possible, make sure it's **really** wide - I'm running 1366x768).

Comment: I had to shorten the URLs, sorry. http://is.gd/x8lDCo and http://is.gd/Jehg1g are examples.

Comment: I found the answer. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it was the FlashBlock extension in Chrome that was causing this problem. I am on version 0.9.31. I set a page to show Flash and it removed the horizontal scrollbar.